# Groovy multithreading stops unexpected

Tags: multithreading, groovy, graph

I try to check if a graph is hamiltonian by generating and checking for random paths on it but the script ends without reaching it's result. I also keep a mutex made of a semaphore for the result and this condition is well preserved until the script returns with null and not reaching the final prints.

```
    def pathFinder(){
        def permutation = []
        for (int i = 1; i <= noOfNodes; i++)
            permutation.push(i)

        while(true){
        if( mutex.tryAcquire(MAX_TIME,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) )
        { println "mutex acquired"
            if(finalFound){
                //check if another thread solved the problem
                mutex.release()
                println "mutex released - solution found"
                break
            }
            println "solution not found"
            //release the lock while checking the permutation
            mutex.release()
            println "mutex released for others to start looking"
            permutation = permutation.sort { new Random().nextInt() }
            println "permutation generated: "+permutation
            if(isPathHamiltonian(permutation)){
                if(mutex.tryAcquire(MAX_TIME,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                {
                println "mutex acquired for result"
                finalPermutation = permutation
                finalFound = true
                mutex.release()
                println "mutex for result released"
                break}
            }
        } 
        }
    }


    def threads = [] 

    noOfThreads.times(){
        def thread = Thread.start {
        pathFinder()  
        }
        threads << thread
    }
    println "I start waiting"
    threads*.join(MAX_TIME)
    println "I joined the finished"

    if(finalFound == true) println "Graph is proven to be hamiltonian : " + finalPermutation
    else println "Graph was not found hamiltonian"
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't reach the end of the script.

Answer (score 0):

the following simplified code works fine:

```
def noOfThreads = 3
def MAX_TIME = 30000
def threads = [] 

def pathFinder(id){
    def t=System.currentTimeMillis()
    println "thread $id start"
    Thread.sleep(3000+id*100)
    println "thread $id end: ${(System.currentTimeMillis() - t)/1000} sec"
}

println "START"
noOfThreads.times{id->
    def thread = Thread.start {
        pathFinder(id)
    }
    threads << thread
}
threads*.join(MAX_TIME)
println "END"
```

result:

```
START
thread 0 start
thread 1 start
thread 2 start
thread 0 end: 3.002 sec
thread 1 end: 3.1 sec
thread 2 end: 3.2 sec
END
```

even if you'll have exception in any thread this code reaches the end.

so, multi-threading works fine and the problem somewhere in the rest of your code.

provide runnable code, so we can see the problem ...